# H264 video stream stuffed with 0xff

Tags: c++, sockets, video-streaming, h.264, packet

I am using recvfrom() to receive data over a socket. I was expecting my buffer to contain a solid stream of data, but it seems to periodically be broken up by chucks of 0xFF bytes. I am using VLC player for streaming the H264 video.

My question is where are these 0xFF bytes coming from? Are they set by the VLC player? I know they aren't packet separators because I am successfully parsing all of my sequence numbers. If they are not part of the packet, how do I safely remove them? Some examples below:

```
80 a1 12 63 
88 7f b9 32 
79 11 3 98 
47 40 44 31 
41 0 ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff 0 0 
1 c0 0 70 
80 80 5 21 
0 1d c f7
```

and

```
1d a7 77 77 
47 40 44 32 
40 0 ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff ff ff ff 
ff 0 0 1 
c0 0 71 80 
80 5 21 0 
1d 1f 55 ff
```

**Update**

I am using RTP. The segments above are only a chunk of a much larger packet. Here is some info about my stream:

:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=56,venc=x264{profile=baseline},fps=12,width=176,height=144,acodec=mp3,ab=24,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:rtp{dst=192.168.0.96,port=9999,mux=ts} :sout-keep

One of the reasons I don't think 0xFF is supposed to be there is because my decoded output looks very corrupted. You can also see that there is a RTP start code 0x000001 directly after the 0xFF segment.

Comment: Please provide the command line example of how VLC is being used. In general H.264 bitstream may containt 0xFF bytes, thats fine. If you would specify the format (since it could be RTP or something else) we would be able to understand the values of the first bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the packets being transmitted over the network from the origin using wireshark, I have found that the 0xFF is actually part of the message. The packets are also of consistent length with 0xFF included. I have determined that I am receiving the data correctly. My problem must be elsewhere.